# How to load more element from web pages using BeautifulSoup and/or selenium

Tags: html, selenium, beautifulsoup, click, infinite-scroll

I would like to get each link that the each boxes contain, the page is  https://www.quattroruote.it/listino/audi

In this webpage there are all the model that this brand is producing, and each model is a boxes that links to another page (the one in which I should work with).

My problem is that the initial page do not load all the boxes the first time, you have to **scroll down and press the red button** "Carica altri modelli" (which mean "Load other models").
Is there a way to automatically store in one variable all the links that i need? For example, the first links of the first box is "/listino/audi/a1"

Thanks in advance to anyone who try to help me!!

Comment: were you able to solve this issue with beautifulsoup? I have to get all hotel details from google but i have to scroll down for the page to load but i have to learn selenium for that so wondering how you solved it

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Not sure exactly what links you want, but you can make the requests iterating through the `itemStart` parameter.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

for i in range(1,100):
    print('\t\tList start %s' %i)
    url = 'https://www.quattroruote.it/listino/ricerca-more-desktop.html'
    payload = {
        'area': 'NEW',
        'itemStart': '%s' %(i*8),
        '_': '1634219611449'}
    
    response = requests.get(url, params=payload)
    
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
    links = soup.find_all('a', href=True)
    
    for link in links:
        print(link['href'])
```